# Error: could not read valid configmap "istio" from namespace "istio-system": failed to convert to proto

Tags: istio

team,
When i'm trying istio-0.3.0, get an error. Any tips? Thanks!

$ kubectl apply -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f myservice.yaml)

    `Error: could not read valid configmap "istio" from namespace  "istio-
    system": failed to convert to proto. unknown field "controlPlaneAuthPolicy" 
    in istio_proxy_v1_config.ProxyConfig - Re-run kube-inject with`-i 
     and ensure valid MeshConfig exists
    error: no objects passed to apply
`
But I checked, configmap is right there in namespace  "istio-system"

$ kubectl get configmap -n istio-system

    `NAME                                    DATA      AGE
    istio                                   1         2m
    istio-ingress-controller-leader-istio   0         2m
    istio-mixer                             1         2m`

FYI, what i've done before that

    `curl -L https://git.io/getLatestIstio | sh -
    cd istio-0.3.0
    kubectl apply -f install/kubernetes/istio-auth.yaml
    namespace "istio-system" created
    clusterrole "istio-pilot-istio-system" created
    clusterrole "istio-initializer-istio-system" created
    clusterrole "istio-mixer-istio-system" created
    clusterrole "istio-ca-istio-system" created
    clusterrole "istio-sidecar-istio-system" created
    clusterrolebinding "istio-pilot-admin-role-binding-istio-system" created
    clusterrolebinding "istio-initializer-admin-role-binding-istio-system" created
    clusterrolebinding "istio-ca-role-binding-istio-system" created
    clusterrolebinding "istio-ingress-admin-role-binding-istio-system" created
    clusterrolebinding "istio-sidecar-role-binding-istio-system" created
    clusterrolebinding "istio-mixer-admin-role-binding-istio-system" created
    configmap "istio-mixer" created
    service "istio-mixer" created
    serviceaccount "istio-mixer-service-account" created
    deployment "istio-mixer" created
    customresourcedefinition "rules.config.istio.io" created
    customresourcedefinition "attributemanifests.config.istio.io" created
    customresourcedefinition "deniers.config.istio.io" created
    customresourcedefinition "listcheckers.config.istio.io" created
    customresourcedefinition "memquotas.config.istio.io" created
    customresourcedefinition "noops.config.istio.io" created
    customresourcedefinition "prometheuses.config.istio.io" created
    customresourcedefinition "stackdrivers.config.istio.io" created
    customresourcedefinition "statsds.config.istio.io" created
    customresourcedefinition "stdios.config.istio.io" created
    customresourcedefinition "svcctrls.config.istio.io" created
    customresourcedefinition "checknothings.config.istio.io" created
    customresourcedefinition "listentries.config.istio.io" created
    customresourcedefinition "logentries.config.istio.io" created
    customresourcedefinition "metrics.config.istio.io" created
    customresourcedefinition "quotas.config.istio.io" created
    customresourcedefinition "reportnothings.config.istio.io" created
    attributemanifest "istioproxy" created
    attributemanifest "kubernetes" created
    stdio "handler" created
    logentry "accesslog" created
    rule "stdio" created
    metric "requestcount" created
    metric "requestduration" created
    metric "requestsize" created
    metric "responsesize" created
    metric "tcpbytesent" created
    metric "tcpbytereceived" created
    prometheus "handler" created
    rule "promhttp" created
    rule "promtcp" created
    configmap "istio" created
    customresourcedefinition "destinationpolicies.config.istio.io" created
    customresourcedefinition "egressrules.config.istio.io" created
    customresourcedefinition "routerules.config.istio.io" created
    service "istio-pilot" created
    serviceaccount "istio-pilot-service-account" created
    deployment "istio-pilot" created
    service "istio-ingress" created
    serviceaccount "istio-ingress-service-account" created
    deployment "istio-ingress" created
    serviceaccount "istio-ca-service-account" created
    deployment "istio-ca" created`

Answer (score 1):

I am suspecting you once installed previous version of istio and thus your `istioctl` is still referring to the old one. To confirm this: does `istioctl version` prints out version 0.3.0?

`getLatestIstio` script does *not* install to your $PATH actually, it exists within `istio-0.3.0/bin`. Please run your command like `kubectl apply -f <(./bin/istioctl kube-inject -f myservice.yaml)`.